# Does two related statement in java override each other inside a for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I know if i have a cycle for like:

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++) { 
      a[i][0] =i+1;
}
```

I know in first iteration a[0][0] = 1;
In second one a[1][0]=2 and so on

If i have again the same cycle for like the one above

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {        
    a[i][j] =evl (a[i][0],b);
}
```

I know in first iteration i will have a[0][0] = something that evl method produce
In second one a[1][0]=something that evl method produce 
 because I have fixed j loop which is not shown here . Now since i use as the first parameter of evl method the one i have used to my first loop i want to use them both as below:

```
 for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
   a[i][0] = (byte) (i+ 1);       
     a [i][j]= (byte) evl (a[i][0],b);    
 }
```

Now i want to know if i use them both as it is shown to the last loop can i have the same value as i will use them as the first and second loop were there was only one statement . I am afraid if they can override each other . Maybe override is not the exact word here because override in java means something else has to do with polymorphism but i do not know what word to use instead of override . Hope to be clear of what i have wanted

Answer (score 1):

The assignment `a[i][j] = (byte) evl (a[i][0],b);` will overwrite the value assigned to `a[i][0]` by `a[i][0] = (byte) (i+ 1);` when `j==0`.

Whether that is acceptable or not in your code is hard to say, since you only posted a small part of your code.

Of course, you can always replace the second statement with

```
a [i][j]= (byte) evl ((byte) (i+ 1),b);
```

which would eliminate potential problems that may arise from this overwriting, but without knowing the context of this loop, it's hard to say if that's the correct thing to do.

Comment: i think your replacement is enough .

Comment: this a[i][0] argument to method evl i have taken when i have calculated this method evl as  private int (byte x , byte [] a) so i think if i cast it as (byte) i+1 it will work